# Using same type for LINQ-to-SQL mapping on different tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ-to-SQL data context in which two tables exist with different names but identical structures. One table (called CallRecords) holds live/current data, and the other (CallRecordsArchive) holds older records - but with the same field names as the live one.

With the basic mapping LINQ to SQL creates two classes CallRecord and CallRecordsArchive - but since they are the same I'd like to avoid this if possible? That way I don't have to write two queries for each instance?

I did consider creating a JOIN view but with millions of rows in both tables it would be a performance nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use inherit for this issue
check [this link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/01/linq-to-sql-inheritance.aspx) for more details.
[one more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384467.aspx)
I hope it is help you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers: the first is more the reverse of my situation (one table, multiple classes, where I want multiple tables, same class). I can't use mapping files as I have the DBML and 99% of the tables are generated from this. I was trying to figure out if I could get the SQLMETAL generator that creates the code to re-use the CallRecord type for both tables. I think I may have to write them as stored procedures that return tables

Comment: You can make an indexed view instead if the two tables have data that should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: LINQ to SQL does not support this form of inheritance. It doesn't matter if you use SQLMetal, the designer, or manual attributes. @jpierson's is the option you would need to use in LINQ to SQL. Note, with the view option, you will need database triggers or stored procs for any updates/inserts so that the DB engine can pick the right table.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've dealt with this is to create an interface for the common aspects of both tables and have both of the generated classes from your data context implement that interface through the use of the a partial class definition. This way when you want to deal with the type as a single concept you can always refer to it as the interface.

Comment: This would work for C# but unfortunately my datacontext is in VB.NET, and VB.NET's interface implementation does not permit this, since you have to tag the methods as "Implements [myinterface].[mymethod]", which won't work as the code is auto-generated by .NET